# why DbSet<T>.Add() is designed to support tracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm new to EF, just a question on `DbSet<T>.Add()` tracking feature.

I can understand that `DbSet<T>.Update()` does need to support tracking because EF needs to check which properties has been changed then  generate correct update statement to avoid unnecessary updates in non-modified columns.

But why `DbSet<T>.Add()` also needs to support tracking? Because when we use .Add() method, we want to add a brand new record into the table in database. Since the data model is new, every property should be included in the Insert SQL statement that will be sent to the database, so there is no points to  track the newly created object, EF just need to include all properties to generate Insert SQL.

Comment: But what if you want to add, and then for whatever reason, update the same record?

Comment: Tracking in general means EF Core keeps track in some internal list the entity instances and their state. Otherwise how it will know to generate insert SQL during `SaveChanges` if it doesn't keep track of objects passed to `Add` calls?

Comment: It seems that you are confused about the concept of tracking entities and why it is done. Look at this sample https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/change-tracking-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: @CodeCaster  what do you mean by update the same record?

Comment: @IvanStoev   sorry I still don't get it. Let's say we have an Employee class with Id(long) and Name(string) properties), and we create an employee object. then we add this object by `DbSet<Empolyee>.Add(newEmpolyee)`, since Id is 0 be default, EF knows that it needs to generate an Insert SQL to the database, then EF just need to get the Name property for the job, so there is nothing EF needs to track, isn't it?

Comment: It still needs to track the object instance with State = Added. Probably you are confused with tracking property values - original, current etc. That's different functionality. Again, tracking means that DbContext contains your object and information whether it is added, modified, deleted or just loaded.

Comment: @IvanStoev how about we just tell from the key property?  if the primary key property is 0, then it is "added", if it has any values other than 0, then it is "modified",isn't that easier for EF rather than setup tracking?